# Why does Google detect my Raspberry Pi as a Mac?

Tags: pi-3

I just logged into my Google account from a Raspberry Pi and I got a notification that a Macbook just accessed my Google account.

Why does Google detect the Raspberry Pi as a Macbook?

Comment: How are you accessing the internet? If it is through ethernet, or built-in wifi, presuming this is based on [MAC address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_address) (which it most likely is), then they should have got it right, because those use a prefix (`b8:27:eb`) assigned to the "Raspberry Pi Foundation" (unless they've run out of the ~17 million addresses that fit in the last three bytes).  However, if you are using an external adapter then it will depend on the MAC used by that.  You should edit in the "link/ether" address (*not the IP*) shown for the interface by `ip link`.

Comment: You need to tell us how you "logged in" (e.g., via a web browser?) and what software you were using (which web browser?). For web logins Google is probably working off the [user agent header](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent) which may have misleading things in it depending on what browser you're using and what plugins (such as ad blocking) you have installed.

Comment: This used to happen with `Ephiphany` which uses `Webkit`. I am unsure about the new new browser. The result, in any event, is based on the identity string the browser sends. Don't worry about it. (I used to customise the identity Firefox sends, but this is now prohibited.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Chromium browser on my Pi3 identifies itself as:-

```
Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux armv7l) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.84 Safari/537.36
```

You can check what User Agent ID and User Agent String Information you are sending at 
http://www.microsystools.com/products/http-user-agent/